# parse_ini_string show only certain results

Tags: php, html-table, ini

I have written some code that parses information from a .ini file into a table.

```
<?php
            $datas  = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents( 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=pathtoinihere' ), true);
        ?>

        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
            <tbody class="points-cell">
                 <tr>
                    <td class="points-header"><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td class="points-header"><b>Points</b></td>
                 </tr>

                 <?php
                     foreach( $datas as $section => $data ) {
                     ?>

                 <tr>
                    <td class="points-section"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $section ); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Points"] ); ?></td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php
                        }
                     ?>
             </tbody>
        </table>
```

Currently this exports the following:

```
Name       |    Points
name1      |    50
unwanted   |    7377
name2      |    22
```

I want to make it so as the .ini file is parsed, the name 'unwanted' and the points related are not parsed.

The way I figure this should be done, and please correct me if I am wrong:

```
         foreach( $datas as $section => $data ) {
         if($section=="unwanted"){
            $section=="";
         }
```

This is where I get lost. Any guidance helps more than you know.

Comment: `if{}` ? Well, it probably should be `if($name=="unwanted"){`

Comment: so from there, how would I omit 'unwanted' so it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `continue` keyword in PHP for your unwanted items:

```
 foreach( $datas as $section => $data ) {
         if($section=="unwanted") continue;
}
```